# iOS Simulator generates an error when I press any digit button in my calculator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

***Hello!***

I have a trouble in 21.2 exercise. In that exercise I build Fraction calculator. I have 9 buttons and math actions. When I press any digit (either 1,2,3 or any else) on iOS Simulator it generates an error:

```
    2012-08-05 15:09:05.026 Fraction_Calculator[834:f803] -[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00
2012-08-05 15:09:05.029 Fraction_Calculator[834:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b5022 0xeb5cd6 0x14b6cbd 0x141bed0 0x141bcb2 0x14b6e99 0x1b14e 0x1b0e6 0xc1ade 0xc1fa7 0xc1266 0x403c0 0x405e6 0x26dc4 0x1a634 0x139fef5 0x1489195 0x13edff2 0x13ec8da 0x13ebd84 0x13ebc9b 0x139e7d8 0x139e88a 0x18626 0x28ad 0x2815)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

*What that means:* "**unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00**" and "**'-[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00'**".

*Here is my code of that program:*

**ViewController.h**

**Code: Objective-C**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Calculator.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;

-(void) processDigit: (int) digit;
-(void) processOp: (char) theOp;
-(void) storeFracPart;

-(IBAction) clickDigit: (UIButton *) sender;

-(IBAction) clickPlus;
-(IBAction) clickMinus;
-(IBAction) clickMultiply;
-(IBAction) clickDivide;

-(IBAction) clickOver;
-(IBAction) clickEquals;
-(IBAction) clickClear;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

**Code: Objective-C**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    char                op;
    int                 currentNumber;
    BOOL                firstOperand, isNumerator;
    Calculator          *myCalculator;
    NSMutableString     *displayString;
}

@synthesize display;

-(void) processDigit:(int)digit
{
    currentNumber=currentNumber*10+digit;

    [displayString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", digit]];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(IBAction) clickDigit:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int digit=sender.tag;

    [self processDigit: digit];
}

-(void) processOp: (char) theOp
{
    NSString *opStr;

    op=theOp;

    switch(theOp)
    {
            case '+':
                opStr=@"+";
                break;
            case '-':
                opStr=@"-";
                break;
            case '*':
                opStr=@"*";
                break;
            case '/':
                opStr=@"/";
                break;
    }

    [self storeFracPart];
    firstOperand=NO;
    isNumerator=YES;

    [displayString appendString: opStr];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(void) storeFracPart
{
    if(firstOperand)
    {
       if(isNumerator)
       {
           myCalculator.operand1.numerator=currentNumber;
           myCalculator.operand1.denominator=1;
       }
        else
            myCalculator.operand1.denominator=currentNumber;
    }
    else if (isNumerator)
    {
        myCalculator.operand2.numerator=currentNumber;
        myCalculator.operand2.denominator=1;
    }
    else
    {
        myCalculator.operand2.denominator=currentNumber;
        firstOperand=YES;
    }
currentNumber=0;
}

-(IBAction) clickOver
{
    [self storeFracPart];
    isNumerator=NO;
    [displayString appendString: @"/"];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(IBAction) clickPlus
{
    [self processOp: '+'];
}

-(IBAction) clickMinus
{
    [self processOp: '-'];
}

-(IBAction) clickMultiply
{
    [self processOp: '*'];
}

-(IBAction) clickDivide
{
    [self processOp: '/'];
}

-(IBAction) clickEquals
{
    if (firstOperand==NO)
    {
        [self storeFracPart];
        [myCalculator performOperation: op];

        [displayString appendString: @"="];
        [displayString appendString: [myCalculator.accumulator convertToString]];
        display.text=displayString;

        currentNumber=0;
        isNumerator=YES;
        firstOperand=YES;
        [displayString setString: @""];        
    }
}

-(IBAction) clickClear
{
    isNumerator=YES;
    firstOperand=YES;
    currentNumber=0;
    [myCalculator clear];

    [displayString setString:@""];
    display.text=displayString;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstOperand=YES;
    isNumerator=YES;
    displayString=[NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:40];
    myCalculator=[[Calculator alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that the code is attempting to call method `digit5` on an object that does not have a method called `digit5`. If this is a method that your button is calling, you need to define it in your view controller class, presumably along with `digit0`..`digit9` methods.

Having ten methods may be suboptimal, though: a better approach would be to tag the buttons with tags corresponding to their respective digits, use the same method for all digit buttons, and harvest the tag inside the invocation.

`tag` is an `NSInteger` property of `UIView`, defined as follows:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
```

Comment: But on clickDigit method I used "sender" variable for working with tags.

I mean that when I press any digit button that variable will get tag from that button. I have to write more code to make it work?

Comment: @user1454115 The method itself will be slightly longer, because instead of a specific hardcoded digit you'd use the value of `[sender tag]`. However, overall amount of code will go down, because instead of ten methods you would have only one method that works for all digits.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new in programming in Objective-C. I don't know how to write that code. Can you write that code? Thanks.

Comment: Look, I use that code for buttons:
<pre>-(IBAction) click1: (UIButton *) sender<code>
{
    int digit=sender.tag;
    [self processDigit: digit];
}
-(IBAction) click2: (UIButton *) sender
{
    int digit=sender.tag;
    [self processDigit: digit];
}<code>

Comment: @user1454115 Your code is correct. Rename `click1` to `clickDigit`, and connect events of all ten buttons to the same `clickDigit` method. You do that in the Interface Builder. Then remove `click2`, `click3`, and so on.

Comment: Oooh... Very strange. When I use click1, click2, and so on everything goes Ok, but when I delete all of them and wrote 1 method called clickDigit with THE SAME CODE and connected all buttons with that method I again got an error. :( ??? Hmmm... 

How did you add code (or that "click1") in special form?

Comment: @user1454115 What is the error you're getting with a single method? Is it a runtime or a build-time error? Could you show the error message?

Comment: I get an error when I press any digit button. It was the same error that I got earlier (that is, "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00" and "'-[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00'"). How did you add code (or that "click1") in special form in comments when you answer on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @user1454115 If you see unrecognized selector error with `digit5`, then you did not re-wire your events in the interface builder: they still point to `digit1`, `digit2`, and so on. To put code in the comments, use backward quotes ` (located on the same key as the tilde `~` character).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15003/discussion-between-user1454115-and-dasblinkenlight)